# didn't get value of arrayist size for looping even arraylist is not empty -android

Tags: android

I want to set text my dynamical button with my ArrayList (allcabs),
but when I running the project it's suddenly close

my Activity

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/layout"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

my onCreate():

```
 Button btnUniversal;  ProgressBar ppb;  Boolean success = false;
 ConnectionClass connectionClass;

 ArrayList<String allcabs = new ArrayList<();

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu_ppu);

         ppb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ppbarSubPPU);
         ppb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

         SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
         orderData.execute();

         int x = allcabs.size();
         for(int i=1; i <= x; i++)
         {
             LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             Button btn = new Button(this);
             btn.setId(i);
             final int id_ = btn.getId();
             String cabangs = allcabs.get(i);
             btn.setText(cabangs);
             linear.addView(btn, params);
             btnUniversal = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
             btnUniversal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                     Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                             "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                             .show();
                 }
            });
          }
      }
```

and this is my SyncData()

```
 public class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String
     {
         String msg = "Internet Error";

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() { ppb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... params)
         {
             try
             {
                 Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                 if (con == null) {
                     success = false;
                 } else {
                     String query = "Select Distinct a.kodecabang, " +
                                     "       b.nama_cab, " +
                                     "       Count(a.kodecabang) As jumlah " +
                                     "From historyReqDCA a " +
                                     "Inner Join kodecabang b " +
                                     "On b.INISIAL COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = a.kodeCabang " +
                                     "Where a.lastStatus = 'Approved by Pemcab' " +
                                     "Group By a.kodecabang, " +
                                     "         b.nama_cab";
                     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                     if (rs != null)
                     {
                         while (rs.next())
                         {
                             try
                             {
                                 allcabs.add(rs.getString("nama_cab")+ " ["+rs.getString("jumlah")+"]");
                             }
                             catch (Exception ex)
                             {
                                 ex.printStackTrace();
                             }
                         }
                         msg = "Found";
                         success = true;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         msg = "No Data Found";
                         success = false;
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                 e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                 msg = writer.toString();
                 success = false;
             }
             return msg;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(String msg)
         {
             ppb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             if (success == false)
             {
             }
             else
             {
                 try
                 {
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

when I debug this, I got 4 value from `allcabs.size()` and get the text of the ArrayList from `allcabs.get()`

please give me enlightenment.

Comment: When you say the project suddenly closes, do you mean the app crashes? If so, please post the resulting exception including the stack trace (i.e. from logcat).

Comment: sorry, when i said "suddenly close" i change "for(int i=1; i <= x; i++)" to "for(int i=1; i <= 4; i++)"

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code in a function and call the function after getting all cab details

```
int x = allcabs.size();
    for(int i=1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(i);
        final int id_ = btn.getId();
        String cabangs = allcabs.get(i);
        btn.setText(cabangs);
        linear.addView(btn, params);
        btnUniversal = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
        btnUniversal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                        "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
       });
     }
```

call from when u add data in arraylist.
it would help u.

Comment: i follow your advice, create a function dynamicButton () and i put the code your suggest into it after that i call it after SyncData(), when run the project not suddenly close again but i just get blank view. the button not show up,

Comment: in this line you are start the loop from indexing 1 and last to arraylist size that time it shows you indexoutofboundexception ...    
for(int i=1; i <= x; i++)

Follow this line                 for(int i=1; i < x; i++)

it would help u

Comment: still blank even i change "for(int i=1; i <= x; i++)" to "for(int i=1; i < x; i++)"

Comment: please check  arraylist size before loop .

Comment: i checked the x using "if (x > 0 )" it's return 0, but if debug i get 4, to count arraylist using size() rigth?